# Need to let user upload video using GWT

Tags: gwt, video

I need to let users upload videos in GWT site, and after uploading I should allow them to preview it. I don't need any controls, just a play and stop button would be enough so that I can show them a preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading the video to your server is the easy part - that's what the [`FileUpload`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html) Widget is for. You just need to write some sort of end point on the server side - a servlet, PHP script, etc. that will receive the file and store it somewhere.

The tricky part is the preview - AFAIK, you need a media streaming server for that. The only free and good one I know is Red5 ([site1](http://osflash.org/red5), [site2](http://code.google.com/p/red5/), [site3](http://red5.org/) - don't know which one is the current one =_=).
An alternative would be to use an exisiting media streaming site that exposes an API for users to upload videos - like [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html). The docs show [how to upload a file](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#Uploading_Videos) (directly from the user, or from your server) to the YouTube service - in return you'll get a link or HTML code to embed on your site.